# how to post invisible solutions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, markdown, spoilers

Please check out: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/863211/4997

In order to not totally give away the answer to the reader, the responses are invisible, unless your mouse hovers over them.

In general this can be done using some javascript or HTML (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16903105/how-to-make-the-text-hidden-in-hover)

How is it being done here on Math.SE - which has restricted rules for HTML ?

Comment: See [tag-wiki for spoilers](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/spoilers/info) for some additional links. Maybe some other posts tagged ([meta-tag:spoilers]) might be of interest for you, too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to be that if you do >! at the beginning of a line, you get that. You could have found that out by clicking edit post and looking at the source.

> hello world

for example.

Comment: It seems to be a new feature as of this year. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-markdown-support-for-hidden-until-you-click-text-aka-spoilers/71396#71396

Comment: @johnmangual That post is from 2010. It has been edited this year.